# eventListener singulares para elemento de um array

Tags: javascript, json, api, lista-encadeada, event-listener

Estou trabalhando com uma API que após tratado me retorna um um array com 2 campos, "código e "modelo" do qual eu extraio apenas os dados de modelo e aplico eles a uma lista no meu html.

Nesta lista, pretendo adicionar um eventlistener para cada um desses elementos separadamente porém o resultado que consigo sempre é aplicado simultaneamente para todos os elementos adicionados pela API e não somente ao que recebeu o 'click'.

A minha dúvida seria sobre como fazer com que cada elemento tenha seu próprio eventlistener.

Segue o código

```js
fetch('https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas')
  .then(res =>res.json())
  .then(jsonResponse =>{       
    
    const dataCars = jsonResponse.map(modelo =>{             
      return `<li>${modelo.nome}</li>` // modelo.nome modelo.codigo
    })
      
      const carModel = dataCars.join(" ")
      document.querySelector("#carsList").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", carModel)    

      for (const car of dataCars){
        addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log(car)
        })
      }
  })
```

Comment: "pretendo adicionar um eventlistener para cada um desses elementos separadamente" já tem ai um `foreach`, basta fazer o addEventLister no elemento `car`

Comment: Olá, Ricardo, obrigado pela sua resposta!

Fazendo "car.addEventListener('click', function() {..."

o console me retorna "car.addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: nesse momento ainda não é um objeto, precisa pegar os itens depois do `insertAdjacentHTML` para ser objetos que apontam para elementos html para poder adicionar o event listerner

Comment: Muito esclarecedor. No momento estou trabalhando nesta aplicação para tentar um estágio na área. Muito obrigado mesmo por fazer parte do meu trajeto! :D

Comment: precisando só pergunta que tentamos ajudar